# android content provider query builder

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have  variables, each of them with the possibility of being empty. I use these  to create my arguments:

```
String[] arguments = {argClassOfExercise, argPeriodOfPeriodisation, argAgeGroup, argPrDistanceGroup, argVo2Max};
```

and to define my WHERE CLAUSE I use

```
String selection = "catalog.ex_class = ? AND catalog.period = ? AND catalog.age_group = ? AND catalog.pr_comp_grouping = ? AND catalog.vo2max = ?";
```

putting it all in my cursorloader:

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), CatalogProvider.CONTENT_URI_TRANSLATION, projection, selection, arguments, null);
```

Now this will all work fine until one of the variables is empty. Since none of the database values will be equal to and empty string. Is there a possibility to exclude a WHERE  CLAUSE if that particular variable is empty?

I know you can write a bunch of IF statements but that would result in me writing 11 of them and I don't think that's really efficient.

Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to use an SQL expression like `(ex_class = ?1 OR ?1 = '') AND ...`, but this would be very inefficient.

You should construct the SQL selection string and the arguments array dynamically, and just leave out any entries for emptry strings.